# Poisson's Equation in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, voltage

I have a question about a specific step in this problem that comes from 'University of Chicago Graduate Problems in Physics', Cronin, Greenberg, and Telegdi.

> A long hollow cylindrical conductor of radius $a$ is divided into two parts by a plane through the axis, and the parts are separated by a small interval. If the two parts are kept at potentials $V_1$ and $V2$, show that the potential at any point within the cylinder is given by
> $$
> V=\frac{\left(V_{1}+V_{2}\right)}{2}+2 \frac{\left(V_{1}-V_{2}\right)}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2 n-1)}\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^{2 n-1} \cos (2 n-1) \theta
> $$

[image]

When cross-referencing my solution with that of the textbook's, I see that I have the correct approach. Using the Poisson equation,

$$
\nabla^{2} V=0=\frac{\partial^{2} V}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} V}{\partial \theta^{2}}
$$

and separation of variables yields:

$$V=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^{m}\left[A_{m} \cos (m \theta)+B_{m} \sin (m \theta)\right]$$

Now

$$V(r=a, \theta)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left[A_{m} \cos (m \theta)+B_{m} \sin (m \theta)\right]$$

$B_m=0$ by symmetry since $V(\theta) = V(-\theta)$. $A_m$ is calculated using the orthogonality of trig. functions, and the boundary conditions of $V_1$ and $V_2$,

$$
\int_{-\pi / 2}^{\pi / 2} V_{1} \cos n \theta d \theta+\int_{\pi / 2}^{3 \pi / 2} V_{2} \cos n \theta d \theta=\frac{2\left(V_{1}-V_{2}\right)}{n} \sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)=\pi A_{n}
$$

but I don't understand how to correctly find the $A_0$ term. The solutions have the following statement:

$$
\pi\left(V_{2}+V_{1}\right)=2 \pi A_{0}
$$

I'm not sure how this comes about.

Comment: It would help if you published your starting equation, as well as the boundary conditions. If so, I'd gladly look at your solution.

Comment: I added the starting Poisson equation. The boundary conditions I refer to are the $V_1$ and $V_2$ of the two pieces of the conductor.

Comment: Thanks. Let me have a look at it now.

Comment: I don't think yu want $A_0$ (for $m=0$) I think your 'counter should start at $1$: look at the solution you quoted: it starts at $n=1$

Comment: @Philip Tbh Philip, I'm not finding OP's result *at all*. My separ. of var. yields something different altogether.. So I need to solve that discrepancy first.

Comment: @Gert I actually didn't check the rest of the solution, but the one part of it I was certain of was the $\frac{V_1 + V_2}{2}$  :P (see my answer below for why). Though from memory, I vaguely  remember solving a problem like this a while ago and it looked sort of reasonable...

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much exactly how you do a Fourier decomposition. The term $A_0$ is usually called the "DC" component of the decomposition, and is obtained by simply integrating the function that you're decomposing as a Fourier sum (in your case, it's $V(a,\theta)$).

You should be able to show that $$A_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} V(a,\theta)\text{d}\theta,$$

since all the sines and cosines integrate out to zero, leaving only a constant term behind. But this integral is quite trivial to do in this case, since $$V(a,\theta) = \begin{cases}V_1 \quad 0 < \theta < \pi \\ V_2 \quad \pi< \theta < 2\pi\end{cases},$$

and so $$2 \pi A_0 = \int_0^\pi V_1 \text{d}\theta + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} V_2 \text{d}\theta = \pi\, (V_2 + V_1).$$

A much nicer (and quicker!) way to do it would be to realise that $A_0$ is the value of the potential when $r = 0$, which is exactly in between the two halves of the cylinder, at its centre. By symmetry, the potential at that point *must* be the average of the potential on either side, by cylindrical symmetry about the axis.

Comment: Very clear, thanks. +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks, the symmetry argument is what I had originally, but I haven't been able to convince myself that it works. I can see that the "potential must change smoothly from $V_1$ to $V_2$" if you are on the rim, $r=a$, but is this necessarily the case for all $r$? Is $V(r,0) = (V_1+V_2)/2$? Because if it isn't the case, then all the symmetry argument gives you is for $r=a$: $(V_1+V_2)/2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1)^n A_n cos(0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n$. And I don't think this gives you $A_0$.

Comment: You're completely right, I was wrong. $A_0$ is the potential when $r=0$, i.e. $A_0 = V(0,\theta)$, the potential at the center of the *cylinder*, which, by symmetry, must be $\frac{V_1 + V_2}{2}$, since all the other contributions must cancel out. I'm changing it :)

Comment: I can finally confirm the whole solution to be correct.